# What photograph technology is appropriate for site/datacenter documentation?

Tags: datacenter, physical-environment, documentation

I manage 500+ sites and need a better visual way of documenting and walking people through a given datacenter.

I'm considering taking several (hundred) pictures and stitching them together so that I can get a better view of the layout and environment.

Microsoft has few interesting programs.  One is an unsupported exe called [Image Composite Editor](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/69699e5a-5c91-4b01-898c-ef012cbb07f7/), another is called Photosynth, which supports an interactive 3D display of photos.  The drawback is that the images are stored on Microsoft's servers, and I'm unsure if they default to a public or private view.

How have you dealt with this challenge, and what tools have you used to solve it?

Comment: Did this work for you? Please follow up :)

Answer (score 7):

[**Google Business View**](http://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/businessview/) seems like the *pro* option ;)

Good luck.

Comment: This will make the contents of my data center public? I don't want the confidential workings of my data center on any server besides one I own...

Comment: You don't have to make the photos public. But Google has a worldwide network of independent photographers who will handle the photography for you.

Answer (score 0):

check out...

http://www.easypano.com/

They even have "panoramic" camera heads that range in price(200-700).
They even have a google "authorized" head that fits their min requirements.

And if that wasnt enough, they even have a mobile service. But your
just wanting interior of your datacenters, not a whole city/town.

But I think someone who offers a suite of software and potential hardware solutions
plus a "mobile" unit should be the way to go.